# Image div showing in Safari, Chrome and IE but not in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, html

So I've recently developed a website [here](http://driventosucceed.org) and I was wondering why my image div (the logo) shows up in Safari, IE and Chrome but not in Firefox? I've tried to looking for an answer but nothing has worked. Appreciate the help.

Here's my CSS code:

```
 #logo-header {
padding-top: 70px;
content:url(../img/logo.png);
margin: 0 auto;
outline: 0; max-width: 100%; height: auto;
margin-bottom: -50px;
}
```

and here's how I initialise it in HTML:

```
<div id="logo-header"> </div>
```

Again, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`content` property is not supported on regular elements (I'm surprised that it works in other browsers). If the image is the part of your content, put it in the markup:

```
<div id="logo-header">
  <img src="img/logo.png" alt="Logo">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In place of the attribute `'content'` tries to use `'background-image'`, firefox reads it.

Comment: Ah. Thanks for this - I understand what I've done more now. I think I will just put the image in the markup as suggested below!

Answer (score 1):

Firefox only accepts `content` in pseudo elements lie `before` and `after`.

You can change your css to something like:

```
background: transparent url(../img/logo.png) no-repeat center center;
```

and set an appropriate height (something like `300px`).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `content` use `background`:

```
#logo-header {
background: url(../img/logo.png) no-repeat center;
}
```